# Powershell custom object table manipulation

Tags: powershell

I have a PS object with name, column2, column3, etc. I have 3 names and values in each of the columns for those names. I want to loop through and put into a table name1, column1, name2, column1, name3, column1, name1, column2, name2, column2, name3, column2, name1, column3, name2, column3, name3, column3, etc. is there a way to do this?

I have tried and object for names and one for columns and using a for each loop. I'm trying to automate lines of code instead of using a select object to select each name and column.

```
current code:

    $obj | sort-object Name | Select-object AER, DER, APRO,FPCT
    
    New-HTML {
        New-HTMLSection -Invisible {
            New-HTMLSection {
                New-HTMLTable -DataTable $obj -includeproperty Name, AER -DefaultSortOrder Descending -PagingLength 10 
            }
    New-HTMLSection {
                New-HTMLTable -DataTable $obj -includeproperty Name, DER -DefaultSortOrder Descending -PagingLength 10 
            }
    New-HTMLSection {
                New-HTMLTable -DataTable $obj -includeproperty Name, APRO -DefaultSortOrder Descending -PagingLength 10 
            }
    New-HTMLSection {
                New-HTMLTable -DataTable $obj -includeproperty Name, FPCT -DefaultSortOrder Descending -PagingLength 10 
            }
    }
    
Was looking to do something like this:
    New-HTML {
        New-HTMLSection {
            $Machines = @(
                'Machine1', 'Machine2', 'Machine3'
            )
            foreach ($Machine in $Machines) {
                New-HTMLSection -HeaderText $Machine {
                    $Information = @(
                        'First Information', '2nd Information', '3rd information'
                    )
                    foreach ($I in $Information) {
                        New-HTMLSection -HeaderText $I {
                            New-HTMLTable -DataTable $Machine
                        }
                    }
                } -Direction column
            }
        } -HeaderText "Citrix Machine Information" -Direction column
    } -Online -ShowHTML
```

current and desired output:

[image]

Comment: 1 property = 1 table column. So if you want a table with 9 columns => create an object with 9 properties

Comment: It is a little unclear what you are asking. Are you saying that you want each property name from your object to become a column in a table, and that the value of the property should become the column value? Or are you saying that each property contains multiple values which need to be split into different columns? Or both?

Comment: so already have the object with those columns. instead of doing a $obj | select name, column1,   $obj | select name, column2, $obj | select name, column3, etc. I would like to loop/iterate through the object, and add html code around it.  <Html> name1, column1 <html>,<Html> name2, column1 <html>,<Html> name3, column1 <html>. etc

Comment: So you want a new row consisting of `Name,<Property>`, per property (excluding the name)?

Comment: Use Sort-Object or Group-Object

Comment: the easy way to explain i guess is if you have a PS object with name, Hits, RBIs, HRS. right now i have object | select name, Hits and use PS write HTML to output it into a table like: name Hits ruth 20 Aaron 15  etc. for each stat i have to do that for each column. i was trying to automate the PSwrite code like for each name and hits do this, then for each name and hr do this, etc.

Comment: output like this name hits name hr name rbi
ruth 20 aaron 5 mays 20
aaron 19 ruth 4 aaron 19
mays 14 mays 3 ruth 18

Comment: Rather than try to explain in words, can you add a code sample to your question that shows the “before” and “after” objects and output that you’re trying to achieve? Code that creates the appropriate pscustomobjects would be a lot clearer than descriptions in comments :-)…

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out -thanks everyone.

```
 New-HTML {
        New-HTMLSection {
            $Machines = @(
                'G','PA','AB','R','H','2B','3B','HR','RBI','SB','CS','BB','SO','TB','GDP','HBP','SH','SF','IBB'
            )
            foreach ($Machine in $Machines) {
                 New-HTMLTable -DataTable $tobj -IncludeProperty  Name,$Machine
            }
        } -HeaderText "Citrix Machine Information" -Direction column
    } -Online -ShowHTML
```